# How to architect a WinForms app for hardware control using the MVP pattern?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I am trying to write a WinForms app to control a moving XY stage. In my first attempt I wrote all my logic inside the Form class, I believe this is called "code-behind" and not recommended and I now understand why. I have built several basic applications using the MVP pattern and I want to rewrite my project.

My app will move a stage on a predefined routine, but also allow manual control, so 2 modes. The main components are the UI and stage controller (hardware) that takes serial input.

I want to display the XY location, without direct serial communication inside UI logic. This means there must be a Model of the stage controller, that runs in the background and provides constant feedback and events such as `StageMoved` or `StageStopped`.

In addition, my application may be in the `MovingToEdge` state but doesn't accept any user input until the stage has stopped. I solve this issue with an enum and switch statements for state and if statements inside checking stage movement. Sometimes, my application is "Busy..." and I don't want users to interrupt, such as calibration.

A high-level overview of my current architecture: my UI code only updates the state variable, which when changed, will trigger the function `OnStateChange` that has a switch statement for the state.

Example:

```cs
private void OnStartButtonClick(...) {
  switch (state) {
    case ApplicationStates.Idle:
      changeStateTo(ApplicationStates.MovingToEdge);
      break;
  }
}

// Keep UI responsive, because some methods may take
// long time such as moving the stage and waiting for
// it to stop.
private async Task OnStateChange() {
  switch (state) {
    case ApplicationStates.MovingToEdge:
      Console.WriteLine("Moving stage to edge");
      await Controller.MoveStageToEdge();
      Console.WriteLine("Stage stopped moving");
      break;
  }
}

// This function is called every 33ms
private void OnUpdateUITick(...) {
  switch (state) {
    case ApplicationStates.MovingToEdge:
      if (Controller.IsStageMoving())
        StartButton.Enabled = false;
      else
        StartButton.Enabled = true;
      break;
  }
}
```

How do I implement real-time feedback with MVP in Winforms?

Comment: What exactly is your question, what difficulty are you having? WinForms and MVP don't go well together historically, although I suppose it could be made to work, and any case WinForms is on its last legs. Have you considered using WPF or MAUI?

Comment: @Charlieface I am using WinForms because I never made a Desktop App before and it made it simple, also Microsoft has no plans to deprecate it and even went as far as rewriting it. My question is how do I architecture a system with real time updates. Why doesn't MVP work well? I assumed that MVVM was out of question but MVP can be implemented with C# language features quite conveniently.

Comment: Like I said, I supposed you can, it's just you won't find many examples of it because WinForms is so old. No they don't have plans to deprecate it, but it's not getting any new features. You can use some kind of data-binding but it's pretty fiddly.

Comment: I assume I could run BackgroundWorker each Scope move method call for checking when scopped moved/stopped. Then call `Presenter.HandleScopeStopped()` when the BackgroundWorker stops.

Comment: You usually *connect* (synchronize) the session state with the screen state using Data Bindings.  The binding is usually controlled using Observable objects (events, in event-driven frameworks). So you synchronize your screen and stage states with models that implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` / `INotifyPropertyChanging` interfaces -- @Charlieface No really clear what new features you're talking about here. MVP pre-dates WinForms and it's been introduced in .NET exactly with WinForms (which is far from being *on its last leg*. For the future, let's see how MAUI grows in the dev community)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're working with, given the vague description. If you need a GUI that's *reacting* to changes performed in different manners, you may want to explore patterns derived from MVVM, as [RectiveUI](https://www.reactiveui.net/)

Comment: I come from a control systems background (a long time ago). The classic way to do this is to segregate the UI from the operation, and move commands from the UI through one channel, and state from the operation back to the UI through another. The standard Control.Invoke mechanism could be used for that second channel (updating the UI). Then all you need is something like a simple queue to pass commands along. Once you have the infrastructure (the 2 channels) in place, both the UI and the operations components get simpler - much the same way MVC (etc) can simplify each layer

Comment: @Flydog57 this seems like what I want and .NET already has support for thread channels.